# Timer every 24 hours at a certain time

Tags: c#, timer

I would like to create a timer that calls a method every  24 hours at a specific time. I do not want to do this through Windows Scheduler but instead should be done within the code. Here is the code I am using currently using:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime today = now.Date.AddHours(16);
DateTime next = now <= today ? today : today.addDays(1);

Systems.Threading.TimerCallback callback = new TimerCallback(DisplayMessage);
Systems.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(callback, null, next - now, TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
```

My problem is that if `next` ends up being only a few minutes away from the current time, then the code works and displays the message through `DisplayMessage()`. If the time difference is greater than a few minutes, the code doesn't work, no exceptions, crashes or anything. I have tried placing log statements, message boxes, and break points inside of `DisplayMessage()` to make sure that I am able to properly see when `DisplayMessage()` is called, but no luck.

Comment: Have you taken a look at Quartz.net.

Comment: Obvious first question: are you holding a reference to `timer` until the callback?  That's needed to prevent it from being GC'd.

Comment: @McGarnagle that's probably what it is, I will try it and report tomorrow. That explains why it works in shorter time spans.

Comment: Curious, but just _why_ don't you want to use a scheduled task for this? This is what scheduled tasks are made more, and using services to perform actions once/day is a smell.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example.

```
public class Scheduler {
    private readonly List<Task> _Tasks;
    private Timer _Timer;

    public Scheduler() {
        _Tasks = new List<Task>();
    }

    public void ScheduleTask(Task task) {
        _Tasks.Add(task);
    }

    public void CancelTask(Task task) {
        _Tasks.Remove(task);
    }

    //Start the timer.
    public void Start() {
        //Set the interval based on what amount of accurcy you need.
        _Timer = new Timer {
            Interval = 1000
        };

        _Timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) => UpdateTasks();
        _Timer.Enabled = true;
    }

   //Check to see if any task need to be executed.
    private void UpdateTasks() {
        for (int i = 0; i < _Tasks.Count; i++) {
            Task task = _Tasks[i];

            if (task.ExecuteTime >= DateTime.Now) {
                task.Callback();
                _Tasks.Remove(task);
            }

            _Tasks.Remove(task);
        }
    }

    //Stop the timer when you are done.
    public void Stop() {
        _Timer.Dispose();
    }
}

//Use this to schedule a task.
public class Task {
    public DateTime ExecuteTime { get; set; }
    public Action Callback { get; set; }

    public Task(DateTime executeTime, Action callback) {
        ExecuteTime = executeTime;
        Callback = callback;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the better solution to make the time trigger every second and check the time and any thing you want , I dont think it is expensive process to trigger it every second .
trigirring it every 24 hour is not the normal use of timer

Comment: Triggering it every 24 hours is exactly one of the normal uses of a timer